# Efficient way to convolve with a diagonal kernel with example code

Tags: numpy, scipy, convolution

I need to convolve a matrix using a kernel which is a diagonal matrix. The arrays are very large, the matrix is about 70000 x 70000 and the kernel about 601 x 601 (kernel has a odd number of entries to perform symmetric convolution) entries. I want to do zero padding at the edges, so the padding has to be 300 in this case, hasn't it?
What I already tried is

**1)** Using `fftconvolve` which is very fast but it needs a lot of RAM, so it is not capable to solve the problem at hand.

**2)** Using `convolve2d`, this seems to work but the calculation is already running for 3 days, it takes to much time.

**3.)** I wrote a pretty simple code to convolve and I am using the advantage of having a diagonal matrix as a kernel. Is it better to avoid the packages and using the code below? What do you think? Do you have a better or faster solution than this?

```
import numpy as np

def convolve_with_diagonal(matrix, diagonal_matrix):
    # Get the dimensions of the input matrix and diagonal matrix
    m, n = matrix.shape
    d = diagonal_matrix.shape[0]
    d = np.diag(d)

    # Calculate the padding required for the input matrix
    pad_width = d // 2

    # Pad the input matrix with zeros
    padded_matrix = np.pad(matrix, pad_width, mode='constant')

    # Initialize the output matrix
    output = np.zeros_like(matrix)

    # Perform the convolution
    for i in range(m):
        for j in range(n):
            # Extract the sub-matrix from the padded matrix
            sub_matrix = padded_matrix[i:i+d, j:j+d]
            print(sub_matrix)
            
            # Element-wise multiplication between the sub-matrix and diagonal matrix
            conv_result = np.multiply(sub_matrix, diagonal_matrix)
            
            # Sum the elements of the convolved result
            output[i, j] = np.sum(conv_result)

    return output
```

I'd appreciate it, if somebody can help me out.

Cheers,
Arch

Comment: What that line is supposed to do? `d = np.diag(d)`

Comment: If your kernel is [separable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_filter), then the computation can be much faster. Regarding the FFT, you can split the array in N band and compute them separately. This require less memory. You need to include some ghost bands around each computed band (so the band needs not to be too small). This solution is used in HPC applications so to compute huge datasets.

Comment: @JérômeRichard But it is not separable. Unless the kernel is 0 (in which case, no need to compute to known that the result of convolution is 0), or has a single non 0 value (in which case, convolution is just a multiplication by a scalar, and a shifting). But if there are 2 or more non-0 elements in this diagonal filter, then... well it is not a diagonal filter if it is separable (if Dᵢᵢ and Dⱼⱼ are both non 0, and D=V.Wᵀ, then Vᵢ, Wᵢ, Vⱼ and Wⱼ must all be non-zero. And then Dᵢⱼ and Dⱼᵢ are also non-0).

Comment: @JérômeRichard That being said, your comment made me think that it should be feasible to use a 1D convolution function (not a self made, even relying on numpy, triple for loop iteration) for this. Which is indeed feasible, with a matrix transform before and after convolution, using the same `as_strided` as in my first answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a stride trick to create an easy to compute sum, and make, roughly what you do (a triple for loop, iterating matrix position and diagonal position), but instead of doing the loop yourself, trick numpy into doing it for you. So, taking also advantage of the diagonality of the kernel, while still relying on numpy

```py
def withStride(matrix, diagonal_matrix):
    m, n = matrix.shape
    d = diagonal_matrix.shape[0]
    D = np.diag(diagonal_matrix)
    pad_width = d // 2
    padded_matrix = np.pad(matrix, pad_width, mode='constant')
    s0,s1=padded_matrix.strides
    MM=np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(padded_matrix, shape=(m, n, d), strides=(s0, s1, s0+s1))
    return MM@D
```

The core element here is obviously `MM` (anyway, all the lines before are the one from your code).
What `MM` is, is a view of `padded_matrix`. It is a 3D array, whose elements are all elements of `padded_matrix`. Its shape is, as indicated, `(m,n,d)`, that is the shape of `matrix`, plus a 3rd axis, being the size of the kernel.

And it is such as `MM[i,j,k]` is what is found in submatrix at `[i,j]` on the kth element of its diagonal. In other words, `MM[i,j,k]` is `padded_matrix[i+k,j+k]`.

But because it is just a view, and just a stride trick, no memory as been allocated for that, and even no computation. `MM` is `padded_matrix`. It is the same memory. The only difference is its shape and stride.

When numpy is accessing an element `[i1,i2,...,in]` of an array, internaly, what it does, is poking into a big chunk of memory, at address `[i1*s1+i2*s2+...+in*sn]`, `(s1,s2,...,sn)` being the "strides" of the array. That is, simply "how many bytes between an element and the next element along axis 1", "how many bytes between an element and the next element along axis 2", ...

If you have already programmed in a lower level language, like C, that is exactly what you would do. For example, for accessing the `B` component of a W×H RGB image, in C, you would typically do `buffer[y*W*3 + x*3 + 2*1]` (usually skipping the last `*1`). Here `W*3`, `W` and `1` are the strides of the 3d array that is an RGB image.

Most of the time, in numpy, when you have an array of shape, say, (100,200,300), of float64, its strides is the size of the data-type, here 8 for `float64` for the last axis, 300×8=2400 for the middle axis, and 200*300*8 for the 1st axis. So (480000,2400,8).

Your `padded_matrix` being a 2d array of shape `(m+2d, n+2d)` of (for example) `float64`, its strides is probably `(s0,s1) = ((n+2d)*8,8)` (I say probably because your `padded_matrix` could already be the result of another stride trick. But it doesn't matter). The point is if `M[i,j]` is at address `addr`, then `M[i+1,j]` is at address `addr+s0`, `M[i,j+1]` at address `addr+s1`, and generally speaking, if `Maddr` is address of `M[0,0]`, then `M[i,j]` is at address `Maddr+s0*i+s1*j`.

Not that we really care. Even using my method, you don't really need to care about memory address. It is just to explain why and how it works.

`MM` is the exact same data as `padded_matrix`, (so same `Maddr` address) except that I've tuned shape and stride. Since shape is `(m,n,d)` it will be a 3D array.
And since its stride is `(s0,s1,s0+s1)`, that means that `MM[i,j,k]` is at address `Maddr+s0*i+s1*j+(s0+s1)*k`, which is the same as `Maddr+s0*(i+k)+s1*(j+k)`. So, the same address as `padded_matrix[i+k, j+k]`.

My explanation is quite lengthy. But in reality, you don't need to think about all that to use `as_strided`. Myself, I though of address and stuff only to type this explanation. My reanning to write the code was more instinctive. I wanted a 3D array of the same shape as M, + a 3rd axis with all the diagonal. So, shape is `(m,n,d)` and strides is `(s0,s1,??)`. The only think to really think about is the `??`. What it means to travel along my 3rd axis: one step along it is a travel of 1 row + 1 column in the original data, so `s0+s1`

So, now, point is, I have, at absolutely no cost (but a headache if you are doing this kind of thing for the first time; but no computation or memory cost), a matrix MM such as `MM[i,j,k]` is `padded_matrix[i+k,j+k]`.
So all that is left to do is, for each `i,j`, to multiply each `k` element by the matching element of the kernel, and sum the result. Which is easily done by `(MM*D).sum(axis=2)`, or, since that operation (multiplying the last axis with a vector and summing) is what a dot product is (matrix×vector multiplication, even if here MM is 3D), it is even easier with `MM@D`. Which has the advantage not to compute the intermediary `MM*D` that would be probably to big to fit in memory (it is the same shape as `MM`. But since `MM` is a view it use no other data than the one from `padded_matrix`. While `MM*D` would really allocate the 70000×70000×601 3D array. `MM@D` on the other hand only allocate memory for the output. 70000×70000 as `matrix`. Which is already way too much for my computer, but if you can't fit your data in memory, then, you have another problem anyway)

which is where the only notable computation  time occurs. This is what does what your double for loop does.

But because the 3 for loops are all internal to numpy (when you have 2 explicit for loops, plus 1 implicit inside `np.multiply`. In fact, I am pretty sure that you have even 2, so 4 in total, since I don't see how numpy could guess that your diagonal matrix is diagonal. So it must be computing lot of `0*...`), it is way faster.

On my (slow) computer, and with an example case of 40×30 matrix with 5 kernel, it takes 122 μs vs 17 ms for your code.

By extrapolating timings I get with 100×100, 1000×1000, 2000×2000, 5000×5000, 10000×10000 arrays (which matches logic: for a constant kernel, the complexity is linear in number of elements in matrix, so O(m×n)), I can deduce that, if, the data were fitting in the memory of my computer, then it would take 1.5 hour to compute.

Comment: Wow! This works for me! Amazing approach! Thank you very much. You asked me what np.diag(D) is supposed to do, but you used it in your code as well. Should I avoid it?

Comment: For comparison: a diagonal matrix with 241 x 241 and a matrix with 1000 x 1000 need ~12 minutes using convolve2d and with your approach ~ 0.1 s which is a factor of ~10^4 less computation time.

Comment: @Archimedes_91, for `np.diag`, yes, I know what it does (it does different things, in fact. It creates a diagonal matrix from a vector of values. or, the opposite, extract a vector of values from a diagonal matrix). But in your code you call it with what is, at that time, an integer (the size of the diagonal matrix passed). Which raises an error. So I was wondering what that line was supposed to do. Then, I, since, figured out that if I just remove this line your code works fine

Comment: @Archimedes_91 So I guess it is just an accidental line remaining from previous version of the code. As least, I don't see what operation is missing when I remove it. (anyway, you use `d` only once after, and it is as an integer, which `d` already is  without this line)

Comment: Oh yeah, it should be `np.diag(diagonal_matrix)`.

Answer (score 1):

I add a second answer (rather than editing the 1st one), because this is another approach (even if it relies on the same `stride_trick`).

Mathematically, what you are trying to do is almost a 1D convolution. In fact, it is a 1D convolution on the diagonals of the matrix.

So, the trick could also be to get a matrix whose lines are the diagonals (the n+m+1 diagonals, including the 2 corners, with only 1 element on each) of your matrix.

This can also be done by padding (not for the same reason as your padding: if I use a real convolution function, it will be able to deal with the 0 itself), and then playing with strides.

What I do in the following solution, is add n-1 lines on top and bottom of the matrix. Then use a stride trick to obtain a matrix such as `MM[i,j+k]` is (with a shift to includes all values. Otherwise some value are relocated to negative indexes) `matrix[i+k,j+k]`.

Then I use `scipy.ndimage.convolve1d` to perform the convolution.
Then, I shift back the strides to create the wanted result.

Theoretically, especially considering the fact that stride tricks are for free, that should be the same timing as my previous solution.
But because in my previous solution I ended up reimplementing convolution with a matrix multiplication (efficiently sure, but not as efficiently as a function whose it is the sole job), it end up being twice faster than my previous solution on my PC.

It use more memory. Almost twice as much. Not a memory explosion, but still, since the previous solution was already using some memory (anyway, your matrix are big, so  any solution that compute on the whole matrix at once has to have the whole matrix in memory). On one hand, I can avoid the `d//2` padding with 0 on all sizes, because `convolve1d` already know how to pad with virtual 0 (in mode 'constant'). On another, I need the padding of `n-1` on top and bottom, and `n-1` is, usually, way bigger than `d`.

And it also compute twice as much linear combination: my previous solution was doing not a single useless computation. This one computes almost half of linear combination with all 0 values that are not retained in the final result.

And despites this, it is still twice faster, if you can afford the memory usage.

```py
def Convol(matrix, diagonal_matrix):
    m, n = matrix.shape
    d = diagonal_matrix.shape[0]
    # Note that np.diag wouldn't be necessary of only the diagonal values were passed. The diagonal_matrix here is just an expansive way to pass d values.
    # [::-1] is necessary because convolve1d (and convolution in general) is 
    # not a set of scalar product (Σvec[i+k]×kernel[k]), but a convolution
    # (Σvec[i-k]×kernel[k])
    D = np.diag(diagonal_matrix)[::-1]
    padded_matrix = np.pad(matrix, ((n-1,n-1),(0,0)), mode='constant')
    s0,s1=padded_matrix.strides
    MM=np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(padded_matrix, shape=(m+n-1,n), strides=(s0, s1+s0))
    # convolve each line of MM, that is each diagonal of matrix 
    # with the 1D-kernel D. mode='constant' pad with 0 for computation.
    Conv=scipy.ndimage.convolve1d(MM, D, mode='constant')
    # os0,os1 are probably the same thing as s0,s1. But why take the risk 
    # (for example, if, for some reason, Conv has not the same dtype...)
    os0,os1=Conv.strides
    # rearrange convolution result in lines again. 
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(Conv[-m:], shape=(m,n), strides=(os0,os1-os0))
```